# How do I display results using onBlur?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onblur

So I'm trying to make a search form that when it loses focus, it will use another function to search for something and display the results.

So when I type in a word, after I click elsewhere, it will display results.

In my jsx file I have my render function and my blur function.

```
render(){
     return <form>
             <span className = "name"> Search Term: </span>
             <input id = "search-term" value = {this.state.value} onBlur = {this.onBlur} </input> 
          </form>
}
```

So I can get to my onBlur function just fine since I was able to just add a console.log("hello world") in my onBlur function and it worked.
But how would I render more lines of HTML only when I lose focus, for example, this would only show up when I lose focus:

```
<div>
    <div class = "result">
         [data or whatever the result is]
   </div>
```

Would this be put in the onBlur function or my render function?

If it's the render function, would I need some sort of conditional statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should be simply setting the state of your component with the results, and letting react render the updated results into the div. Here's an example:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  onBlur = async () => {
    const results = await axios.get('myhttpendpoint');

    this.setState({
      results
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <span className = "name"> Search Term: </span>
          <input id="search-term" value={this.state.value} onBlur={this.onBlur} />
        </form>
        <div id="results">
          {this.state.results}
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}
```